# Invalid Operands to binary %?

Tags: c

I don't know what is wrong and why I get this error. I've searched around and I can't figure it out for the life of me.

```
void print_arb_base(unsigned int n, unsigned int b) {

    char output[36] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    int t = n; //Keep track of the number

    int s = 0; //The space we are currently on
    while(pow(b, s) < t) {

        s++;

    }

    s--;

    for(int i = s; i >= 0; i--) {

        int r = t % pow(b, i); //Gets number that goes into this part of base number
        t = t - r * pow(b, i);

        printf("%c", output[r]);

    }

}
```

Comment: You're either writing C, or you're writing C++. Which one is it?

Comment: C, sorry. Didn't realize

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks everyone. I didn't know that pow was a double value that was returned

Comment: this seems to be assuming that the number 'n' is in base 10.  That will greatly limit what operations can be performed.  suggest an additional parameter that indicates the original base.

Comment: Yes the number that's taken is going to always assumed base 10.

Answer (score 2):

The modulus operator (%) only works on integral operands while pow() returns a double.  You need to either cast its result to an integral type or, more safely, use a call like lrint() that will round to the nearest integral result.  Maybe you mean:

```
int r = t % lrint(pow(b, i));
```

If you are trying to print a number in an arbitrary base, then you probably mean:

```
unsigned long div = b;

while (div <= t)
    div *= b;

div /= b;

for(; 0 != div; div /= b) {
    unsigned long d = t / div;

    t -= d * div;

    printf("%c", output[d]);
}
```

Comment: So how would I go about making this work how I intend it to? Am I going at it all wrong?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your code is trying to accomplish, but I'll post code that probably does what you intend.

Comment: Trying to convert any number n to base b

Answer (score 0):

The function `pow` returns a double value.

You cannot mod that with an int value.

You could do

```
int r = t % (int)pow(b, i);
```

To get rid of the error, but it may or may not still do what you want.

Comment: The only issue I have now is that if I input 1452 to base 12 I get C00 instead of A10

Comment: I think you have your logic backwards then.